# Unable to set button's location in java swing application

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton, layout-manager

I am new to Java and was trying to develop a basic swing application. I wanted to set the location of the button on the `JFrame`. I tried to do this but was unable to do this this is my code. I am using eclipse for development

```
public class MyUI extends JFrame {

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Click");
    JTextField tb1 = new JTextField(5);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    public MyUI() {
        super("Test");
        setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setVisible(true);
        button1.setVisible(true);
        panel1.add(button1);
        add(panel1);
        panel1.setLocation(10, 10);
        button1.setLocation(10, 10);    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
        button1.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyUI gui = new MyUI();
        gui.setSize(400, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you seem not to use layout, look the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: Is there a reason you use panels when you are not using layouts? Also: Is there a reason, you are not using layouts?

Comment: Do.Not.Use.Null.Layout.Ever - LayoutManagers are there for a reason, which is to take over all the dirty details in locating/sizing components, make use of them!

Answer (score 2):

1.why you put two `JComponents` to the same `Bounds`

```
panel1.setLocation(10, 10);
button1.setLocation(10, 10);
```

2.have look at [Initials Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

3.`public class MyUI extends JFrame {`

should be

```
public class MyUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
```

4.don't extend `JFrame`, create a local variable

5.`setVisible(true);` should be (in this form) only last code line into `MyUI()` constructor

6.`setVisible(true);` is important issue, you visibled `JFrame` and then to add `JComponent`(s)

7.don't use `NullLayout`, use proper `LayoutManager`, in the case that you remove `this.setLayout(null);` and  `panel1.setLayout(null);` added `JComponents` could be visible

8.use `pack()` before `setVisible(true)` as last two code lines in constructor

EDIT (by using `built_in LayoutManagers`, `BorderLayout` for `JFrame` and `FlowLayout` for `JPanel`)

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton button1 = new JButton("Click");
    private JTextField tb1 = new JTextField(5);
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

    public MyUI() {
        super("Test");
        panel1.add(tb1);
        panel1.add(button1);
        add(panel1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyUI testing = new MyUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Button is inside panel so the button's location is relative to panel.

Comment: could be (sometimes) miss_speled by JVM, this is tax for using NullLayout without Insets

Comment: _public class MyUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener_ no: a) don't extend JFrame b) do not expose api that's not meant for public usage, or in other words: don't implement any interface instead create an instance internally and use that

Answer (score 0):

Your panel and button are not seen because they have zero size. Add something like:

```
panel1.setSize(100, 100);
button1.setSize(80, 30);
```

or use the `setBounds` method which is more convenient to set location and size simultaneously:

```
panel1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
button1.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 30);
```

Comment: this forum isn't opened for `AbsoluteLayou`t, +1 only against `donw_voters`, never to use `NullLayout` without `Insets`, never by setBounds(), use `Insets` that returns near parents

Comment: -1 (as @mKorbel anticipated ;-) null layout is the wrong thingy to do in very near-to 100% of contexts ... instead, choose and use a LayoutManager that does what you want

Answer (score -1):

Would like to suggest something, though its not the direct immediate answer to your question, but still its important from my point of view....

You can use `Group Layout` which was developed by NetBeans team back in 2005, its awesome to work with.... Try using the `Windows Builder Pro` which is provided by Google for free now... You can get your application up and running in no time......